# Why sleeping the main Thread changes behaviour of the running other Thread in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

Here is my code:

```
/* User: koray@tugay.biz Date: 21/02/15 Time: 21:52 */

public class MyThread extends Thread {

    int x = 0;

    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread running..");
        while(x == 0) {
        }
        while(x != 1) {
            System.out.println("x is" + x);
            // do something else time consuming
            try {
                sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void foo(int y) {
        x = y;
    }

}
```

When I run TestClass like this:

```
/* User: koray@tugay.biz Date: 21/02/15 Time: 21:55 */

public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        MyThread myThread = new MyThread();
        myThread.start();
        //Thread.sleep(1000);
        myThread.foo(3);

    }
}
```

I see in the console:

```
Thread running..
x is3
x is3
x is3
x is3
```

which is ok..

But when I **uncomment** the //Thread.sleep(1000); I expect the same behaviour, only after 1 second.. But all I see in the Console is.

```
Thread running..
```

No matter how long I wait..

Why?

Comment: @Mat What do you mean? I am setting the x to 3 after a second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to let Java know that the value of `x` might be updated by another thread by using the `volatile` keyword:

```
volatile int x;
```

Comment: Having said that, using `.wait()` and `.notify()` is probably the pattern you want to use for this.